# Android card based game, need help to start

Tags: android, xml, button, playing-cards

I'm just setting out in android development. I want to make a kind of card based game. I'm just looking for suggestions really on how I might start it.

I know I have to make the menu layout and view, then use an Intent from that to get to the main game view. My sticking points are:

- There's going to be a deck of cards. It's going to be a set number so I was thinking I could just have each card defined as a button in the layout. I don't know if that is the right way to do it though.
- Storage of card details. I'm thinking of using an xml file to store these.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to check out this project: 
http://code.google.com/p/bestcardgameever-android/
And a post of the author about this (there is a second post in the same blog):
http://developreality.blogspot.com/2009/05/overcoming-absolutelayout-deprecation.html

Comment: The code was useful to browse through, even though it is still based on the older API v3. I liked this project's layout style and Activity setup. But the blog wasn't too helpful.